# How to identiyfy issues in structure or missing values in netCDF-file that contains weather data?

Tags: dataset, data-cleaning

during processing of weather data files (wind x,y 10m), i get the follwing error:

- *height3' not present in all datasets and coords='different'. Either add 'height3' to datasets where it is missing or specify coords='minimal*

This error messages likeliy to originate from here: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/main/xarray/core/concat.py

Inspceting the files, one for each day of the month, i do not find errors, i checked:

- Column names - seems OK
- Missing nan/null - seems OK
- Checking all height3 values and they are all 10 -Seems OK
- Checked all datatypes of the values for each file - Seems OK

What can i check, and how can i check for incosistency in wind/wetaher files in general?

Comment: If you have narrowed it down already to a specific file, why not run this in a debugger and put a breakpoint on the line in question?